# VC command line compilation strange problem

Tags: command-line, compilation, visual-c++, printf

I searched the net and I cannot find an answer for the problem that I am facing. Im not sure if the title of the question itself describes my issue.
the problem is, I have a file which I am for storing certain formattable strings. For example string could be "Version is %s". And later on during compilation a header file will be created in which the version to be printed will be present. While using the application when the function is called, the string will be formatted (using vsprintf) with the macro and the version will be displayed (eg: "Version is 4.4"). This is working perfectly when Im compiling using the IDE (vc 6 and above). But as soon as I use the command-line options to compile and link the same project the application outputs "version is %s". The formatting is not done. I tried all the way I know but the problem is persisting. Can anyone help me about this? Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Thanks, Sreehari

Comment: And I found out one more thing. The problem occurs only when individual projects (there are more than one .dsp in my dsw) are compiled. When I compiled the entire workspace using the same tool the problem stopped. It is displaying the correct output now. Im going crazy.. something is wrong with the dsw or dsp?